# How to get the Array Class for a given Class in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, class, reflection

I have a `Class` variable that holds a certain type and I need to get a variable that holds the corresponding array class. The best I could come up with is this:

```
Class arrayOfFooClass = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(fooClass, 0).getClass();
```

Is there a way to do this without creating the new instance?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since Java 12, there is the [`arrayType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#arrayType()) method on `java.lang.Class`:

```
Class<?> arrayOfFooClass = fooClass.arrayType();
```

---

Its [implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/fd8a3dcc52dc5d6b62edd83eacef5934f6294e80/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java#L4482-L4484) just calls `Array.newInstance(this, 0).getClass()`.

Answer (score 39):

**Since Java 12**

`Class` provides a method [`arrayType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#arrayType()), which returns the array type class whose component type is described by the given Class. Please be aware that the [individual JDK](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/31ac8714e0593f2feaa8e9ebaf32bab904ba6d11/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java#L4694) may still create an instance of that Class³.

```
Class<?> stringArrayClass = FooBar.arrayType()
```

**Before Java 12**

If you don't want to create an instance, you could create the canonical name of the array manually and get the class by name:

```
// Replace `String` by your object type.
Class<?> stringArrayClass = Class.forName(
    "[L" + String.class.getCanonicalName() + ";"
);
```

But [Jakob Jenkov argues in his blog](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/arrays.html) that your solution is the better one, because it doesn't need fiddling with strings.

```
Class<?> stringArrayClass = Array.newInstance(String.class, 0).getClass();
```

³ *Thanks for the hint to [Johannes Kuhn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845414/johannes-kuhn).*

Comment: He starts with the above and ends up with what I have. So I guess the `newInstance` is the cleanest way to do this.

Comment: It actually works both ways, but you said you don't want to create a new instance.

Comment: True. I was actually looking for a cleaner solution. It is not that I don't want the new instance but that I'd rather not have one :-)

Comment: "This doesn't require creating a new instance of the Class" - [well...](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java#L4483)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn * facepalm *

Comment: The `Class.forName(…)` approach does not only imply fiddling with strings, but also dealing with the syntax. Your code does not work when the element type is a primitive type or an array type. By using `getCanonicalName()` instead of just `getName()`, you made it incompatible with inner classes, local classes, and anonymous classes, which would otherwise work. Since you didn’t specify a class loader, the caller’s class loader will be used. So it’s possible it doesn’t find the class or even ends up at the wrong class. And `Class.forName(…)` doesn’t work with hidden classes in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using the class name.
Just make sure you get the class using it's ClassLoader

```
    Class klass = yourClass;
    boolean init = wantToDoStaticOperations;
    Class.forName("[L" + klass.getName() + ";", init, klass.getClassLoader());
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I for one, like fiddling with Strings. So, here's a more general solution that takes that approach, and still works with arbitrary class types. It is certainly more fiddly than your answer, but anyways, it's more complex to make it generic than the accepted answer gives it credit for, so here is the complete set of code to make it work:

```
    /**
     * Returns the name of the class, as the JVM would output it. For instance, for an int, "I" is returned, for an
     * array of Objects, "[Ljava/lang/Object;" is returned. If the input is null, null is returned.
     *
     * @param clazz
     * @return
     */
    public static String getJVMName(Class clazz) {
        if(clazz == null) {
            return null;
        }
        //For arrays, .getName() is fine.
        if(clazz.isArray()) {
            return clazz.getName().replace('.', '/');
        }
        if(clazz == boolean.class) {
            return "Z";
        } else if(clazz == byte.class) {
            return "B";
        } else if(clazz == short.class) {
            return "S";
        } else if(clazz == int.class) {
            return "I";
        } else if(clazz == long.class) {
            return "J";
        } else if(clazz == float.class) {
            return "F";
        } else if(clazz == double.class) {
            return "D";
        } else if(clazz == char.class) {
            return "C";
        } else {
            return "L" + clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ";";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generically and dynamically returns the array class type for the given class type. The dynamic equivalent of
     * sending {@code String.class} and getting {@code String[].class}. Works with array types as well.
     * @param clazz The class to convert to an array type.
     * @return The array type of the input class.
     */
    public static Class<?> getArrayClassFromType(Class<?> clazz) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(clazz);
        try {
            return Class.forName("[" + getJVMName(clazz).replace('/', '.'));
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            // This cannot naturally happen, as we are simply creating an array type for a real type that has
            // clearly already been loaded.
            throw new NoClassDefFoundError(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Note that this is code from an existing library I wrote, which is why I make use of the getJVMName method. It could probably be modified to keep the dots instead of the /, but given that's how it works, I convert back and forth between the two methods. Anyhow, this works with any class, including nested array types.

Comment: Instead of this `if … else if … else if … else if …` ladder, you can use `if(clazz.isPrimitive()) switch(clazz.getName()) { case "boolean": return "Z"; … }` Or replace the entire `getJVMName` method’s code with `MethodType.methodType(clazz).toMethodDescriptorString().substring(2)`. Starting with JDK 12, `Class` itself has a `descriptorString()` which might be useful for your library but since JDK 12 also has an `arrayType()` method, the descriptor string is not needed for this purpose.

Answer (score -2):

```
Class stringArrayOfClass = String[].class;
```

Comment: I don't know the type in advance; it is in a Class variable. So your method wouldn't work.